# Type of element in Pandas DataFrame does not agree with filter

Tags: python, pandas, filter, types

I wanna check types of elements in Pandas DataFrame columns, but doing it the Pandas way, vectorized, not using loops.
As a toy example:

`dic = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':list('abc')})`

So, when I do:

`dic[dic['a'] == int]`

I expect to see the whole DataFrame, since all of the elements of the column 'a' are int. However, the output shows only the header of the DataFrame. In reverse, when I do:

`dic[dic['a'] != int]`

It outputs the whole DataFrame.
I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

You need call `type`

```
dic['a'].apply(type)==int
Out[8]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is simple and sober solution, learning from your codes buddy, keep it up and keep inspiring all of us cheers :)